# Which Controls do I have to choose in iOS development

Tags: ios, uitableview, tabbed-view

[an iOS app page, which descirbes some item's detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO4Sl.png)

[This is kind of what I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UisWS.png)

[This is exact what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeH8A.png)

Actually I am not an iOS developer.

But a member of our team lacks of knowledge of consisting of iOS app Page(Scene)

I think he usually use table view all the time. which I guess he can't handle very well.

He always struggle about height of UITableView in dynamic pages.

As you see in the picture, page has two views, which I don't know how to call it.

If round button on the right side of a woman is pressed those two views switches.

I guess it's kind of "TAB".

Is it normal that using UITableView in this kind of page. or Which is best practise?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: I googled but have no clue. That's why I posted here. I just want to know which is best practise. and would love to  save him from suffer.

Answer (score 0):

The first image can be made using a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`(`UITableView` will do the job with lesser hassle). For second image, you'd wanna use a `segmented control`. 
The third can be built using `UICollectionView`, however, there are plenty of third party libraries out there on github for the same and you might wanna check them out.

Last but not the least, have some faith in your developer. He seems to be a newbie if he's facing troubles with tableviews but believe me, we've all been there some day.Encourage him to ask questions on various communities. If he's curious enough, he'll be just fine after a while.

Comment: That's what I want to know. third party library. Thank you so much.